# Limit where I can Instantiate on mousedown?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, onmousedown

My script puts an object at the position of the mouse, regardless of the position.

I'd like to limit where I can place the object to a small area around the player sprite.

Say if mouse X if greater than (X position + a little) of the players X than the object wont Instantiate. I've tried if statements along these lines but haven't been able to get it to work.

Here is the placement script.

```
 public GameObject seedlings;
 public GameObject player;
 Vector3 mousePOS = Input.mousePosition;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start(){}
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     PlantInGround();
 }
 void PlantInGround()
 {
     Vector3 mousePOS = Input.mousePosition;

         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {
             mousePOS.z = +12;
             mousePOS = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePOS);
             Instantiate(seedlings, (mousePOS), Quaternion.identity);
             Debug.Log(mousePOS);
         }
 }
```

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working. Leaving it for others. I honestly don't know why the coordinates just lined up. Thanks for the help @Lincon.

public class PlantItem : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public GameObject seedlings;
public GameObject player;
Vector3 mousePOS = Input.mousePosition;

void Update()
{
    if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        PlantInGround();
    }
}

void PlantInGround()
{
    Vector3 mousePOS = Input.mousePosition;

    mousePOS.z = +12;
    mousePOS = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePOS);
    if (((player.transform.position.y < mousePOS.y + 0.5) && (player.transform.position.y > mousePOS.y - 1.5)) && ((player.transform.position.x < mousePOS.x + 1) && (player.transform.position.x > mousePOS.x - 1)))
    {
        Instantiate(seedlings, mousePOS, Quaternion.identity);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I note! Don't forget to remove the **!** from the if statement in the update function!

Answer (score 2):

To check if the your seedling position is near your player's position:

```
float maxDist = 3F; //radius within the player that the seedling can be instantiated
if ( (mousePOS - player.transform.position).magnitude < maxDist )
{
  //Do Something
}
```

You could compare the distance squared instead, since `magnitude` involves a `Sqrt()` call which is expensive, but given that you are doing this only on a mouse click, it shouldn't really matter much.

Of course, you have to be sure that your player is about 12 units away from the camera's forward viewing direction.. given that you are doing this:

```
mousePOS.z = +12;
mousePOS = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePOS);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added the code into mine but when I run the program nothing instantiates. If I swap the < for > things instantiate wherever I click like before. I added a debug.log in the if statement and it doesn't get called either. I put a ! in front of mousebuttondown as well and moved the mouse everywhere to make sure if there was any spot it instantiate. I added HashSet as well so I could see in the Hierarchy if anything was instantiated but just out of sight.

Comment: @michael good that you are debugging to find the problem, that's actually very fundamental to programming. You might want to log `mousePOS` and `player.transform.position` also. If you want to check whether something has instantiated, `GameObject x = Instantiate(...) as GameObject;` and check `if (x == null) Debug.Log(..)`

Comment: Thanks again. I added a log to mouse x and the players x and they are rather different. The mouse x depends on where it is on the play screen bottom left being 0,0. While the player is at 0,0 in the middle of the same screen.

Comment: Strange. If I write `if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && mousePOS.x > playplay.transform.position.x)` It has the same coordinates as the player, as in both are in the middle of the screen at 0,0. But if I change the greater than symbol to face the other way, the 0,0 of the mouse is at the bottom left of the play screen.

Comment: When it is like this "<" nothing is planted regardless of both coordinators. But while it is like ">" then I can place the object anywhere again, regardless of if the mouse x is great than the players x. But I can see on the log that it isn't greater than the players x but I can still instantiate?.

Comment: @michael just note what coordinate system you are in. For `Input.mousePosition`, it is in screen coordinates ((0,0) at bottom left of the screen, while the `z` value is arbitrarily `0`). `player.transform.position` is in world coordinates ((0,0,0) is in the center of your scene world). `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint()` will transform your coordinates from screen to world.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the camera object itself is the thing somehow causing the issue. The Instantiated object gets placed at the cameras Z position. That's why I had mousePOS.z = +12;, I just didn't know why I needed it till now. 

If I put 'mousePOS.x < player.transform.position.x' I can Instantiate  outside of the cameras vision to the left hand side, I can see them being placed in the Scene view. If I put  -400 after '< player.transform.position.x' then it is placed where I want it to, close the the player. But if I move to the left it does not update and I can still only place where I could

Comment: At the start. Actually, if I move the player 100s of units, way outside of the cameras view, it does update where I can place the objects, but it is only by a few units. Sorry to spam it up.

Comment: @michael Since `mousePos` gives you the screen position of the mouse on the camera, `mousePos +=12` is shifting that point `12` units deeper into the camera. It's relative to where the camera is facing, which is why i said `be sure that your player is about 12 units away from the camera's forward viewing direction`

Comment: I am using `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint()`, by the way.